# The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start when running a timer function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I am getting this below error when I am running my timer function app in Azure Cloud. It is just a basic code and I wanted the log to be shown in Insight.

[image: Exception message]

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error below relating to your configured storage account could be a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the workaround I did to identify this issue cause:**

1. Created the **Azure Function** (Stack: .NET 3.1) of type **Timer Trigger** with your given timer `"0 * * * * *"` and the connection string given from the storage account created in Azure portal, which is running successfully (in local):

[image]

***2. Deleted the Storage account from the Azure Portal and tried to run the function locally which gave me the error: `The listener for function Function1 was unable to start.`***

[image]

***Recovered the Storage Account and then deployed to the Azure Portal Function App and running successfully in cloud also:***

[image]

In the Azure Cloud, Yes, as [@Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin) Said that it would be a Storage Account configuration issue.

**Few of the steps to resolve this issue were:**

- Check the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value contains correct the correct storage account connection string.
- Check the Storage account is not deleted.
- Check the Networking Option in the Function App that might be the firewall is blocking/restricting the access to the associated storage account.

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall issue.
Added the appropriate Virtual Network and Subnet  under Storage Account > Networking > Firewalls and Virtual Network