# The listener for function 'Functions.SendNotificationTimer' was unable to start. when running .NET 8 Azure timer function on MacOS locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have a .NET 8 Azure timer function running in isolation mode and trying to debug it locally on my Mac, but keep getting errors when running it. I also have a http trigger function in the same project and it works. I'm seeing both `failed to acquire host lock lease` errors and `The listener for function 'Functions.SendNotificationTimer' was unable to start` errors.

```
[2024-03-10T20:42:50.803Z] The listener for function 'Functions.SendNotificationTimer' was unable to start.
[2024-03-10T20:42:50.803Z] The listener for function 'Functions.SendNotificationTimer' was unable to start. Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)) (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)) (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)) (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)) (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)) (Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000)). Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.
[2024-03-10T20:43:09.115Z] Host instance '0000000000000000000000008F76DCB3' failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.
[2024-03-10T20:43:37.473Z] Host instance '0000000000000000000000008F76DCB3' failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.
[2024-03-10T20:44:03.701Z] Host instance '0000000000000000000000008F76DCB3' failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.
[2024-03-10T20:44:30.433Z] Host instance '0000000000000000000000008F76DCB3' failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.
[2024-03-10T20:44:47.967Z] Retrying to start listener for function 'Functions.SendNotificationTimer' (Attempt 8)
```

Here is the code, but I don't think this is the problem as I also have an http trigger function in this solution as well and it works.

I saw this post, [The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start when running a timer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984814/the-listener-for-function-function1-was-unable-to-start-when-running-a-timer-f), but it was running fine locally.

This post, [The listener for function 'Functions.trigger' was unable to start? while running Azure function locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821547/the-listener-for-function-functions-trigger-was-unable-to-start-while-running), but I'm using Azurite on a Mac. A connection error does flash up at some point, as one of the answers mentions.

[image]

I've followed [Code and test Azure Functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local) and [Use the Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code%2Cblob-storage) for Azurite and [Quickstart: Create a C# function in Azure using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp).

**SendNotificationTimer.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyCompany.Notifications
{
    public class SendNotificationTimer
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public SendNotificationTimer(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SendNotificationTimer>();
        }

        [Function("SendNotificationTimer")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            
            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**notificationFunction.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78127464</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Debug"
      },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
              "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if there is already an instance of that particular host is running, or if the host process is not shutting down properly.

- Find the currently running process using **PORT 10000** and kill that process using its *Process ID*. Refer [Article](https://pimylifeup.com/macos-kill-process-port/) using below commands.

```
lsof -i tcp:<PORT_Number>
kill -15 <Process_ID>
```

- Stop and restart the [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio,blob-storage) manually.
- Or use Azure Storage connection string in the `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

---

**I have created a Function project with both Http trigger and Timer Trigger and working as expected.**

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

**Function.cs:**

```cs
public class SendTimerNotification
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SendTimerNotification(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SendTimerNotification>();
    }

    [Function("SendTimerNotification")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```cs
[2024-03-11T05:51:41.365Z] Found C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp9\FunctionApp9.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-03-11T05:51:51.716Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 9980) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-03-11T05:51:51.803Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7199/api/Function1

        SendTimerNotification: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-11T05:51:52.267Z] Executing 'Functions.SendTimerNotification' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-03-11T11:21:52.2282717+05:30', Id=5775589a-c237-4787-8f06-ec863c76c770)
[2024-03-11T05:51:52.272Z] Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-03-11T09:25:00.0000000+05:30
[2024-03-11T05:51:52.452Z] Next timer schedule at: 3/11/2024 9:25:00 AM
[2024-03-11T05:51:52.452Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 3/11/2024 11:21:52 AM
[2024-03-11T05:51:52.486Z] Executed 'Functions.SendTimerNotification' (Succeeded, Id=5775589a-c237-4787-8f06-ec863c76c770, Duration=245ms)
[2024-03-11T05:51:56.703Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=cdc9e38b-288e-49b4-8fa5-aed0973f803a)
[2024-03-11T05:51:56.751Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-03-11T05:51:57.062Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-03-11T05:51:57.076Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-03-11T05:51:57.156Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=cdc9e38b-288e-49b4-8fa5-aed0973f803a, Duration=464ms)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, as it helps me understand this better. I did run the lsof command with the tcp port of 10000 (which I checked a few times) and it's not listing anything. I will try with remote Azure storage.

Comment: Ok. This helped. Thank you. Rebooted and started the process and used the lsof command to ensure it was running.